# What is the physical meaning of the square of a density operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, density-operator

Let $\rho$ a density operator $\rho: H \to H$ representing a mixed state, with $H$ Hilbert space. The operator $\rho$ (together with its corresponding matrix) represents a mixed state; when it additionally satisfies the property $\rho^2 = \rho$, then it is a pure state.

In any case, I was wondering if $\rho^2$ has any physical meaning at all. Clearly $\rho^2$ will still be self-adjoint because $\rho$ is by definition, but does it have any physical meaning at all? Would it make sense to compute the expectation value of $\rho^2$ as an observable?

Comment: See also here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246258/physical-meaning-of-tr-rho-2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course it has a meaning. It is the quantity providing the quantum [purity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)) when traced,
$$
\gamma \, \equiv \, \mbox{tr}(\rho^2),
$$
so a pure state has maximal purity $\gamma =1$; whereas a maximally impure state proportional to the identity in a *d*-dimensional Hilbert space has minimal purity $\gamma =1/d$.

More elegantly, it is related to the [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)#Linear_entropy) of the system described,
$$
S  = \, -\mbox{tr}(\rho \ln \rho) = -\langle \ln \rho  \rangle \\
 = \langle 1- \rho  \rangle     + \langle (1- \rho )^2 \rangle/2     +   \langle (1- \rho)^3  \rangle /3  + ...  .
$$
One minus the purity  is just the leading term in this Mercator series expansion for the logarithm in powers of $1-\rho$ around the unity. The entropy itself ranges from 0 for pure to *ln d* for maximally impure.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but that’s the physical interpretation of its trace. I was asking if $\rho^2$ has a physical meaning on its own. Admitting it has one and remembering that one can always compute the expectation value for any observable (self-adjoint operator with physical meaning), what would it mean to compute the expectation value for $\rho^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from a "physical interpretation". $\langle \rho ^2\rangle=\operatorname{tr} \rho^3$ enters in the subleading term of the entropy Mercator expansion, beyond linear entropy.  You want a physical interpretation of the cumulant expansion?